# Trying to remove the grave character " ` " that gets prefixed to an expression while submitting from google form or appsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, backticks

I'm trying to run a script after every edit to remove the **`** character that may be added after the edit. The edit of context is an AppSheet (Google cloud) submit. (It was previously a google form that I recently migrated).

It is an expense tracker app and a typical entry in the amount column is say, *=1+2+3.3*, in case the bill is for 3 items or simply *7*, if it is a single item. When submitted, the first one comes as '=1+2+3.3 , which prevents excel from computing its value, which needs manual deletion of the *`* character.

The solution that I thought is efficient is to run a google script that is triggered on onEdit to find and replace this `. Any leads would be really helpful in making some progress. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `onChange` or `onFormSubmit` trigger on AppSheet submission?

Comment: No, onEdit didn't seem to work. Didn't try onFormSubmit.
Is there a chance that an appscript can't work when the sheet is modified with appsheet? 

I had dismantled the script after the created the app because the app used to add data to the next available row and the form used to add the entry to a new row, and the dynamic dependent drop-down that I needed the script for while using form was useless with the app cos it already had it done in the app.

Comment: @DhvinayPV depends, triggers only run based on manual edits/changes so if onFormSubmit doesn't work then you may have to do it retroactively wiht a recurring trigger.